# Runtime.getRuntime.exec() works on Windows but not Linux

Tags: java, linux, runtime.exec

I am building a Java application that calls a system command and executes that command before returning control to the Java thread. The debugging step that I have is that I have made a perl script called test.pl and I call that script from the Java method and in Windows I get the expected output and a return value of 0. In Linux I get no output or error output and I get a return value of 136.  I have spent extensive time online trying to figure out where I have gone wrong but as I have said, on Windows it runs.  I think it must be a simple error that I am just not catching.

Here is the code derived from the excellent Runtime.exec() tutorial at http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

```
try {

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output/" + this.startPosition + ".txt");
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(new String[]{"perl", "/data/stat-positive-selection/thaddeus/treesim/chr2YRI/test.pl"});

//System.out.println(commandLine);
// any error message?
StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new 
   StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");            

// any output?
StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new 
    StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", fos);

// kick them off
errorGobbler.start();
outputGobbler.start();

// any error???
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);

fos.flush();
fos.close(); 
} catch (Throwable e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have figured it out and fixed the code

new exec call, the use of the shell and the path to perl are required

```
Process proc = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/perl /data/stat-positive-selection/thaddeus/treesim/chr2YRI/test.pl"});
```

Comment: Have you verified that you can run `perl /data/stat-positive-selection/thaddeus/treesim/chr2YRI/test.pl` from a command line, as the same user your java code is running as ?

Comment: Don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)!

Comment: I figured it out

new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "/user/bin/perl /pathToTest/test.pl"}

Comment: Note it's `/usr/bin/perl`, not `/user/bin/perl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the whole Runtime.exec() structure with the Apache Commons Exec library. It fixed the problem I was having.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html

Comment: But this doesn't explain why replacing the code fixed the problem, so isn't really going to help other people.

Comment: I have found the same issue. Runs fine on my debug environment and when I move it to my box it seems to cut off parameters or something...would be good if there was a solution for this...

Answer (score 1):

The differences between the old and new versions are:

- you are running the command from a shell, and
- you are specifying the full pathname of the "perl" command.

In fact, in this context there doesn't seem to be a great deal of point in running the command from a shell.  (Hypothetically, your Perl application might depend on environment variables that are set during shell initialization.  However, the same environment variables *would normally* be inherited by and then from the Java command's environment.  So unless the Java command is being launched in a strange way, this scenario is ... unlikely.)

So I think the *substantative* difference<sup>1</sup> is that you are using the full pathname for "perl" ... and you don't a subshell to do that.

So, in the interests of science ( :-) ) I suggest you try this:

```
    Process proc = rt.exec(new String[]{
            "/usr/bin/perl", 
            "/data/stat-positive-selection/thaddeus/treesim/chr2YRI/test.pl"});
```

---

<sup>1 - ... the difference that makes a difference</sup>

Comment: I eventually replaced the whole code with the Apache Commons Exec library.